# How to add change action to radio button without ID and in array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am filling table with values from model.

```
<tbody>
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
  {
    ...
    ...

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Option[i].Date, new {id = Model.Option[i].OptionId})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i].Completed, new {id = Model.Option[i].OptionId})
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...
    ...
  }
</tbody>
```

I need to add Change action to each table radio button (Completed) which, in case if it is true, will dissable Date (will make it uneditable), but the problem is:

How to add .change(function () { ... }); to radio button without knowing its Id (to use it in $(#...))?
Also, how to dissable only Date for current option where radio button state was changed?

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: you can consider adding a class and use class instead of id

Comment: I have thinked about it but the problem with Date are still here. Also I'm not sure will it conflict with other radio buttons if this table will have more that 1 option.

Comment: Do you want to add the change action for all radiobuttons?

Comment: Yep... to all of them.

Comment: If you want to add the change action for all radiobuttons, then you can add a name to all the radiobuttons
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Option[i].Date, "Radios", new {id = Model.Option[i].OptionId})
 and in jquery you can call like below:
$(':radio[name=Radios]').change(function() {
    // read the value of the selected radio
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == '12/12/2014') { //the value from the model
        //disable Date 
    }
});

Comment: I'll try to use name... but the part about date disabling is still dark for me. How I suppose to detect which textbox of date should be dissabled?

Comment: Can you please add complete html? Am unable to find the radiobutton in your html.

Comment: Em... you didn't read a question i guess... Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Option[i].Completed is the radion button. (Completed is bool in model).

Answer (score 0):

First you want to add the .change(function() {...}); to all radio buttons in the tbody. No need to find individual radio buttons by id.

To disable the date, find the form element left of the radio button changed. When the user clicks a radio button, you know which radio button was clicked. Using JQUERY you can easily find the previous form sibling element. More details here: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

If you really, really need to identify the radio button, there are two options:

1. Create an ID for the radio by appending text to the ID of the date. So id="radioBtn-OptionId"
2. Use the ID of the date field as a class on the radio button. Then using JQUERY find the radio button by class rather than ID.

Comment: Not sure that I understand how it suppossed to look.